# Docker build causes system to freeze

Tags: docker

I am trying to run docker build on my laptop, Macbook Pro running Ubuntu 16.04.4, kernel 4.13.0-38 and docker 1.13.1 build 092cba.  Latest updates installed. I also tried a manual install of docker-ce, latest stable version, with the same results.

The containers are based on a RHEL image and the crash happens during yum install step, not sure if that matters or not. Builds run fine on my desktop which runs the same docker version and Ubuntu 16.04.4 4.13.0-37-generic kernel.

Here are the syslog entries for around that time. Laptop utilizes a VPN, which the desktop does not, but both use a proxy.  I have run with the VPN service running but not connected, connected and terminated. Same results for all cases.

https://pastebin.com/U8pU8wjV